# Question on ANTLR grammar rule in TSqlParser.g4 at https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/sql/tsql

Tags: t-sql

In the TSqlParser.g4 file

```
    1.On line 3247, a rule predicate is defined as
    predicate
         expression comparison_operator expression
    In turn comparision_operator is defined as
    comparison_operator
        : '=' | '>'

 | '<' | '<' '=' | '>' '=' | '<' '>' | '!' '=' | '!' '>' | '!' '<'

2. On line 3166, a rule expression is defined as
expression
     expression op=('*' | '/' | '%') expression
```

Why would someone write a rule one way or the other ? The predicate rule too could have been written as "expression op=( '=' | '>' | '<' | '<' '=' | '>' '=' | '<' '>' | '!' '=' | '!' '>' | '!' '<' expression". Or the expression rule could have been written as "expression divMultModOperator expression" with divMultModOperator defined as '*' | '/' | '%'. What are the advantages (or rationale) for writing a rule one way Vs the other ?

Comment: If you press the "blame" button on the source file you will find authors of every line in it; you can then ask them your questions, as they are the only ones who can give you authoritative answers.

Comment: I do not quite follow. The ANTLR site says stackoverflow is the place to ask questions. Is it not correct ? And this is also generic grammar related question, not necessarily related to what the author did/did not do.

Comment: "Why would someone write a rule one way or the other" is in no way a "generic grammar related question"; it's literally a question for that someone who wrote the rule. And the way to find that someone is to check the blame output.

Comment: "the ANTLR site says stackoverflow is the place to ask questions"  This is not stackoverflow.